# Groovy Power Assert Null Check

Tags: groovy, mocking, spock

I have a Groovy class which receives an argument to its constructor and checks it with a Power Assert statement like so:

```
public MyClass(Map args) {
    assert args.firstArg
}
```

Normally the value of `args.firstArg` is an instance of another Groovy class within my project. When I use a real instance of this class, the assertion passes. However when I use the Spock Mocking framework to pass in a mocked instance of the method, the assertion fails:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert args.firstArg
       |    |
       |    Mock for type 'OtherClass' named 'mockOtherClass'
       ['firstArg':Mock for type 'OtherClass' named 'mockOtherClass']
```

However, when I change the code to

```
assert args.firstArg != null
```

then my code works.

Up until now, I had naively thought that

```
assert args.firstArg
```

was just shorthand for doing a null check.

Based on what I have observed passing in mocked class instances this is not the case, and I was wondering if someone can help me to understand what the difference is.

Comment: How are you creating the mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hayfreed: Actually, I do not like to speculate, so please next time (or this time, in case my guess is wrong) provide more than just a set of incoherent code snippets when asking questions on StackOverflow. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read!).

Let us create an MCVE first, shall we?

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765

class OtherClass {}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765

class MyClass {
  MyClass(Map args) {
    assert args.firstArg
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def "do not use mock"() {
    when:
    new MyClass([firstArg: new OtherClass(), secondArg: "foo"])
    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    when:
    new MyClass([firstArg: null, secondArg: "foo"])
    then:
    thrown AssertionError

    when:
    new MyClass([secondArg: "foo"])
    then:
    thrown AssertionError
  }

  def "use mock"() {
    when:
    new MyClass([firstArg: Mock(OtherClass), secondArg: "foo"])
    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
  }
}
```

This test passes. But what if we change `OtherClass` to be a collection type instead?

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765

class OtherClass extends ArrayList<String> {}
```

The test fails in the feature method **not** using the mock:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError'

    at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:118)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClassTest.do not use mock(MyClassTest.groovy:10)
Caused by: Assertion failed: 

assert args.firstArg
       |    |
       |    []
       ['firstArg':[], 'secondArg':'foo']

    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.groovy:5)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClassTest.do not use mock(MyClassTest.groovy:8)
```

So you see that [Groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) is more than a null check. E.g. collection types yield `false` for assertions also if the collection is empty.

But back to your problem. How could the test for the mock fail? My best guess, not having seen the code for your `OtherClass`, is that the class implements an `asBoolean` method, as also described in the manual section about Groovy truth:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765

class OtherClass {
  boolean asBoolean(){
    true
  }
}
```

Now the test failure looks much like yours:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError'

    at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:118)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClassTest.use mock(MyClassTest.groovy:28)
Caused by: Assertion failed: 

assert args.firstArg
       |    |
       |    Mock for type 'OtherClass'
       ['firstArg':Mock for type 'OtherClass', 'secondArg':'foo']

    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.groovy:5)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62543765.MyClassTest.use mock(MyClassTest.groovy:26)
```

How would you fix that? Just stub the `asBoolean` method to return `true`:

```groovy
  def "use mock"() {
    given:
    def otherClass = Mock(OtherClass) {
      asBoolean() >> true
    }
    when:
    new MyClass([firstArg: otherClass, secondArg: "foo"])
    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry that you found my question to be incoherent. I think the test you put together for this is very nice and I will try to replicate something of that sort. OtherClass in this case does not implement an asBoolean() method, so I don't think that's it. But I found the documentation on Groovy truth very helpful as well. I'm going to mark the answer as accepted because there's great detail here which might help someone with a similar problem.